R Regex Oddity when adding [\\W] in front of letter W
I've been trying to figure out this strangeness that is happening with regex functions in R and would appreciate any help you may have.
This was my original function to search for specific words in a scrape of some PDFS
escape_special_chars <- function(words) {
  sapply(words, function(word) paste0("\\b", gsub("([\\W])", "\\\\\\1", word), "\\b"))
}

It was strangely not catching the word "Women" but was working on all other words. I noticed that this was because of the "W" at the start of the word:
escape_special_chars <- function(words) {
  sapply(words, function(word) paste0("\\b", gsub("([\\W])", "\\\\\\1", word), "\\b"))
}

# Is W the issue:
test_words <- escape_special_chars(c("Winter Wonderland", "Walrus", "Wonderful", "Summer", "Dolphin", "Happy Holidays"))

# Outputs:

     Winter Wonderland                        Walrus                     Wonderful                        Summer 
"\\b\\Winter \\Wonderland\\b"              "\\b\\Walrus\\b"           "\\b\\Wonderful\\b"                "\\bSummer\\b" 
                      Dolphin                Happy Holidays 
              "\\bDolphin\\b"        "\\bHappy Holidays\\b" 

I thought that the regular expression "\W" should simply work to show where a word in our specified list ends/begins (see CRAN Regex Readme)). I'm very confused as to why it is adding an extra set of \ only where there is the letter W?
Any guidance you may have would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You should not use  shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions when using TRE regex engine. It should be gsub("(\\W)", "\\\\\\1", word), or there are better ways.
